# access object made by class constructor in c#

Tags: c#, class, constructor, user-controls

I have written a property in a user control class using set get like this :

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{   
  public string ServerName { get; set; } 
  public PagingUserControl()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

then by adding this user control to a windows form project I set ServerName in the "Misc" section of properties window.
now here is the question, how can I access ServerName from another usercontrol ? I think I should access the property "ServerName" of the object made by the constructor of "MyUserControl"

Comment: you could change the `PageUsingControl()` constructor to take in a string serverName variable and assign `this.ServerName = serverName`
`public PagingUserControl(string serverName)`

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to reverse the data flow by extracting your model being the value of the `ServerName` property out of the user control and bind both user controls to it, see [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) for details. This way you can save a lot of time on plumbing and passing data between your components.

---

If you are specifically looking for how to implement this with your existing code then following steps below may be able to help you too. Once you drop an instance of the user control to the form, the designer is going to generate some code for it in the `Form1.Designer.cs` file.

```
// the declaration of your user control
private MyUserControl1 myUserControl11;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // the initialization of your user control
    this.myUserControl11 = new WindowsFormsApp3.MyUserControl1();
}
```

This code makes it possible to access the instance of the user control from the form. If you are asking how to share the value of this property with another control you would need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside your user control.

```
public partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And then subscribe your parent form to this event.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // subscribe to the user control event
    this.myUserControl11.PropertyChanged += 
        new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(
            this.myUserControl11_PropertyChanged);
}

// handle the event by updating the other control
private void myUserControl11_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = myUserControl11.ServerName;
}
```

Once you have notification implemented you may consider looking at how data binding can be used to achieve the data propagation between controls with less code. Hope it helps!